# Which smithing route is the best to get all armor the fastest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I recently had to restart my account on the Xbox 360. One way I went about getting my armor the last time was smithing. I needed daedric armor so I took the right route (Heavy Armor) when leveling up my smithing.

I got the Dragonborn DLC shortly after I received my daedric armor. I made the dragon bone armor when I got it. I have the DLC now from the beginning but I don't know what path to take when upgrading. I have unlocked both dwarven and elven smithing now but I know I will run out of the perks to increase soon.

My goal is to receive the dragon bone armor first and then unlock the rest that isn't unlocked. Which path do I take left or right?

Comment: So are you asking how to get the Dragon Bone armour the fastest? Or *all* armour?

Comment: @Ben It says it at the bottom saying that I want to get dragon bone armor first and then get all of them.

Comment: @Mr. Advice Taking either path first will get you to dragon bone armor before unlocking the rest of the armor (as the bottom paragraph asks), and neither route is faster than the other for getting all armor (like the title asks). I assume the actual question is mean to be "which path gets to dragon bone armor the fastest?", although it's not stated anywhere and isn't really clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be best going left along the Light Armour tree, as shown here:

[image]

Heavy Armour will cost you 5 skill points to reach Dragonbone, whereas Light Armour will only cost you 4. However, both sides will still require a Smithing level of 100.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose the left path I you're using light armor and choose the right path if you're using heavy armor. But if only the skill points matter to you, the left path is shorter.

Answer (score -2):

any path(light[left] or heavy[right]) will get to dragon armor eventually.